# CLLocationManager not getting location

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, cllocationmanager

Hi I am having trouble using CLLocationManager to find the current user location. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
}

- (IBAction)pressed:(id)sender {

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}


#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location"       delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation   *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        NSLog(@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
        NSLog(@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude);
    }
}
```

When I run this code, nothing happens at all. There is no reaction in the debugger. As I understand, didUpdateToLocation is deprecated in iOS6 but I thought it was still usable. If anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong or suggest an alternative please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: It should work even if it's deprecated, a method deprecated doesn't mean "this method is broken, please use the new one". Are you sure the IBAction supposed to start the location manager is triggered?

Comment: @HepaKKes yes everything is triggered. Does that mean all my code is correct? What is the way of doing it without using the deprecated command?

Comment: Hey, dude, since you're using the simulator did you set a location through the debug menu?

Comment: Yea i think that had to do with the problem...not sure but in the end i just restarted and tried with a real device and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

How'd you define stuff in your .h file? I assume like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CLLocationManager.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CLLocationManagerDelegate.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end
```

And the main .m file I ran:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"


@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    return YES;
}


#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location"       delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation   *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        NSLog(@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
        NSLog(@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude);
    }
}
```

Here's the output on the *simulated* iOS:

```
2014-08-12 13:36:28.933 tester[5577:60b] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
2014-08-12 13:36:35.237 tester[5577:60b] didUpdateToLocation: <+37.78******,-122.40******> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 8/12/14, 1:36:35 PM Central Daylight Time
2014-08-12 13:36:35.237 tester[5577:60b] -122.40******
2014-08-12 13:36:35.238 tester[5577:60b] 37.78******
```

Comment: Thanks! So mine is a little different because it is in a SingleView application, not a blank one. I did not import <CoreLocation/CLLocationManager.h> only the <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>. Are there other frameworks that I have to include? Is there also anything else I need to do as far as simulator such as a setting that would allow for location services?

Comment: I got errors prototyping when I didn't include both.

Comment: What xcode are you using? Mine doesn't even recognize it as a framework.

Comment: Xcode Version 5.1.1 (5B1008). Please post your .h file to show protocols.

Comment: Hey I fixed it. Not sure what was wrong but just deleted everythinng and started fresh. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Hey great! Mind accepting my answer if it was correct??